# Return the name of the directory that is located just above the current working directory in Python using the os module

Tags: python-3.x, import, path

I am trying to solve this but is showing me an error, on Python documentation I was trying to find more about the absolute path, and I am not sure if something else is wrong here, thanks in advance. (Sorry I am not sure how to fit the code in the code block part).

```
import os

def parent_directory():

    # Create a relative path to the parent 
    # of the current working directory 

    relative_parent = os.chdir("..")

    # Return the absolute path of the parent directory
    return os.path.abspath(relative_parent)

print(parent_directory())
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import os

def parent_directory():
  relative_parent = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
  os.chdir(relative_parent)
  return(os.getcwd())

print(parent_directory())
```

Suppose the .py file is located in this path:

```
/home/folderA/folderB/getParentDir.py
```

the returned result shall be:

```
/home/folderA/
```

Comment: In your answer are you creating a "path_parent" variable instead of the "relative_parent" variable in my code? Just to be sure

Comment: Yes. The variable name does not matter. I am editing the answer in 1 min to better explain

Comment: Great! Now is working, a long path to work with files and directories in Python for me, just starting.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way, hope this helps.

```
import os

def parent_directory():

    #create relative path for parent
    relative_parent = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..')

    #use abspath for absolute parent path
    return os.path.abspath(relative_parent)

print(parent_directory())
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def parent_directory():
  # Create a relative path to the parent 
  # of the current working directory 
  dir= os.getcwd()
  relative_parent = os.path.join(dir, '/' )

  # Return the absolute path of the parent directory
  return relative_parent

print(parent_directory())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def parent_directory():
  # Create a relative path to the parent 
  # of the current working directory 
  relative_parent = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "/")

  # Return the absolute path of the parent directory
  return relative_parent

print(parent_directory())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you sure this works?  ```os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "/")``` returns the root directory for me.

Comment: same thing for me too :(, I think you should modify the code

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def parent_directory():
  # Create a relative path to the parent 
  # of the current working directory 
  relative_parent = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir)

  # Return the absolute path of the parent directory
  return os.path.abspath(relative_parent)

 print(parent_directory())
```